# Structured Data (schema.org) - Multiple SiteNavigationElement in structured data testing tool

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, structured-data, google-ranking

I extended my navigation with Schema.org attributes and found the following.

Since I use a navigation template that is used in several places on the website, the type "[SiteNavigationElement](http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement)" has also been inserted in several places. As a result, I get several recognized "SiteNavigationElement" types in the google testing tool (see picture). Of course, the url's of the individual navigation items are different, so it looks good at first glance.

But here I wonder if that is positive or negative for google if several "SiteNavigationElement" types are recognized?

[image]

Comment: 1) Asking for SEO advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can ask if something is correct/good according to Schema.org, but not whether Google likes/dislikes it. 2) What are these different `SiteNavigationElement`s for, why does a page has more than one? 3) Are you marking up each single navigation link? If yes, how?

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Answer (score 0):

According to specification of SiteNavigationElement:

> A navigation element of the page.

There are no restrictions on the number of navigation elements for web pages. Accordingly, there are no restrictions for this property on one web page. However, if you have a navigation list with URLs on your web page, the best solution is to apply the property **[BreadcrumbList](http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many SiteNavigationElement elements in your page as you wish. Schema is pure about the semantics, it does not put limits in how many elements you use.

> The SiteNavigationElement markup can help increase search engines’
>   understanding of your site structure and navigation and can be used to
>   influence organic sitelinks.

See: https://searchengineland.com/schema-markup-structured-data-seo-opportunities-site-type-231077